# User Entered Data is not saved on Firebase_realtime_database

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

User Entered Data is not saved on Firebase_realtime_database.I tried making a personal information form . But when I click on submit button , the data entred by user is not saving in firebase(real-time database). What could be error?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_form_builder/flutter_form_builder.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class DonorRegistration extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
 DonorRegistration({Key key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _DonorRegistrationState createState() => _DonorRegistrationState();
}
}

class _DonorRegistrationState extends State<DonorRegistration> {
 var data;
 bool autoValidate = true;
bool readOnly = false;
bool showSegmentedControl = true;
final GlobalKey<FormBuilderState> _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormBuilderState>();

final ValueChanged _onChanged = (val) => print(val);

var currentItemSelected3;
bool disabledropdown = true;
final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
String _gender = 'Male';

final TextEditingController _ageController = TextEditingController();

final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("donor");
```

This is UI area

```
enter code here
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(1500, 0, 5, 1),
    title: Text('Donor Registration'),
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
    child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                radius: 65.0,
                child: Image.asset('lib/assets/logo.png'))),
        FormBuilder(
          // context,
          key: _fbKey,
          // autovalidate: true,

          readOnly: false,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Personal Information'),
              SizedBox(height: 15),
              FormBuilderTextField(
                attribute: 'Name',
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.account_circle,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
                  ),
                  labelText: 'Full Name',
                  hintText: 'Enter Your Full name',
                ),
                validators: [
                  FormBuilderValidators.required(
                      errorText: 'This field required')
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.name,
                //controller: _nameController,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              FormBuilderRadioGroup(
                attribute: 'radio_group',
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    //value: gender,
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.person_pin,
                      color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
                    ),
                    labelText: 'Gender'),
                onChanged: _onChanged,
                options: [
                  FormBuilderFieldOption(value: 'M', child: Text('Male')),
                  FormBuilderFieldOption(value: 'F', child: Text('Female')),
                  FormBuilderFieldOption(value: 'O', child: Text('Other')),
                ]
                    .map((_gender) => FormBuilderFieldOption(
                          value: _gender,
                          child: Text('$_gender'),
                        ))
                    .toList(growable: false),
                validators: [
                  FormBuilderValidators.required(
                      errorText: 'This field required')
                ],
              ),
           

              SizedBox(height: 15),
              FormBuilderTextField(
                attribute: 'age',
                // autovalidate: true,
                controller: _ageController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  labelText: 'Age',
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.confirmation_number,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 0, 0, 1),
                  ),
                ),
                validators: [
                  FormBuilderValidators.required(
                      errorText: 'This field required')
                ],
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),

              FormBuilderSwitch(
                label: Text('I Accept the tems and conditions'),
                attribute: 'accept_terms_switch',
                initialValue: true,
                onChanged: _onChanged,
              ),

              SizedBox(height: 15),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: MaterialButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                child: Text(
                  'Submit',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
                    dbRef.push().set({
                      "name": _nameController.text,
                      "age": _ageController.text,
                      "gender": _gender,
                      "disease": _diseaseController.text,
                      "blood_group": _blood,
                      "body_part": _donate,
                      "Hospitals": _hospital,
                    }).then((_) {
                      Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
                          SnackBar(content: Text('Successfully Added')));
                      _ageController.clear();
                      _nameController.clear();
                    }).catchError((onError) {
                      Scaffold.of(context)
                          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(onError)));
                    });
                  } else {
                    print(_fbKey.currentState.value);
                    print('validation failed');
                  }
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(
                child: MaterialButton(
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              child: Text(
                'Reset',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                _fbKey.currentState.reset();
              },
              )),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
  }

@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _ageController.dispose();
  _nameController.dispose();
  }
}
```

please tell me what could be errors.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: There isn't any error. But after clicking on Save button , the information should store in database. But these is not happening. Nothing is displaying in real_time_database. Is there something that I had missed while coding?

Comment: Have you tried to just write to the database with some hardcoded data to check that the most basic of writes works? I would try that if you haven't just to narrow down the issue to your code and not how you have firebase set up, and then you can work backwards on the issue from there.